# Restrict the properties of a POJO class to hold same value

Tags: java, validation, pojo

I have a class where in I have two properties of type boolean.The condition is both should not be same,that is if one property holds false value,then other must hold true value and vice versa.I am using net.sf.oval dependency for validations.How can I implement the above said scenario.Is it possible ?thanks

My Class

```
public class Modality {

    private boolean fp;
    private boolean otp;

    public boolean isFp() {
        return fp;
    }

    public void setFp(boolean fp) {
        this.fp = fp;
    }

    public boolean isOtp() {
        return otp;
    }

    public void setOtp(boolean otp) {
        this.otp = otp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Modality [fp=" + fp + ", otp=" + otp + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the point of having two fields, in this case ? Could not you just have getters and setterd play with very same field ?

Comment: @ Laurent G I do agree with you,we can have only field.but I have been told to use two fields,then what to do?

Comment: Hum, exercise on oval. As @JureKolenko said, use `@NotEqualField` plus add a constructor that let you respect the invariant.

Comment: thanks, but how to add a constructor that me respect the invariant?

Comment: Where are those instances instantiated ? With what ?

Comment: jersey instantiate those instances

Comment: From the user guide, I'd say @Guarded(applyFieldConstraintsToSetters=true)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void setOtp(boolean otp) {
    this.otp = otp;
    this.fp = !otp;
}

public void setFp(boolean fp) {
    this.fp = fp;
    this.otp = !fp;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response,but I have to restrict the client from sending the same value in the json. I will not be changing anything

Answer (score 0):

Use the [@NotEqualToField](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/NotEqualToField.html) annotation?

```
public class Modality {

    private boolean fp;
    @NotEqualToField("fp")
    private boolean otp;

}
```

Comment: but when we create modality object,the properties of  this class will be initialized with default value which is false.then again it will be same values to the properties.isn't it?